# CSS to print dash "-" after end of paragraph

Tags: html, css, printing

I need to add dashes at the end of certain paragraphs of an html page that will also be printed. I found some CSS that almost does this, but it doesn't work while printing.

```
<html>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    @media print{
        ul.leaders {
            max-width: 40em;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            list-style: none
        }
        ul.leaders li:after {
            float: left;
            width: 0;
            white-space: nowrap;
            content:
             "--------------------"
             "--------------------"
             "--------------------"
             "--------------------"
        }
        ul.leaders span:first-child {
            padding-right: 0.33em;
            background: white
        }
        ul.leaders span + span {
            float: right;
            padding-left: 0.33em;
            background: white;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1
        }
    }
    </style>    
    <body>
        <ul class=leaders>
            <li><span>Almond Prawn Cocktail, with orange and potato salad, spring carrots, blue cheese, tuna, oh yes, and prawns</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Making the advised changes and using < p > elements.
Thanks for the help.

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    @media all{
        p.puntitos:after{
            float: left;
            width: 0;
            white-space: nowrap;
            content:
             "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
        } 
        p.puntitos span:first-child{
            padding-right: 0.33em;
            background: white
        } 
    }
    </style>    
    <body>
        <p class="puntitos">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </p>

        <p class="puntitos">
            <span>Eros massa sociis, porttitor morbi neque eget.</span>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: “Almost does this”? What exactly does it do, and what doesn’t it do that you expected? And what “paragraphs” and “dashes”? There are no `p` element and no dash characters in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple lines like that in the `content`, all of the extra parenthesis besides the first and the last are ignored. So you might as well take them out

```
content: "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/fufuzaco/3/edit) (using `@media all` instead of `@media print` to demonstrate)

As noted by Careless, you also must remove `media="screen"` on the `<style>` tag because it conflicts with the print

Comment: You also need to remove `media="screen"` on the style element (when using `@media print`).

Comment: Still doesn't work when I want to print. Thanks though. And for some reason the multiple lines in content do work in safari and chrome

Comment: Thanks @Careless, I guess I was careless when I copied that example. Can you answer the question so I can mark it as answered.